# how does {addRecords : true} work?

Tags: json, extjs

I have a store with a list of user entries. Each time a user is added, I want to add all entries of that user to the store without removing the old ones.

I have a JSON web service that returns all entries of a user to me.

I read the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load
and if I understand correctly, I should be able to do sth like:

```
myStore.proxy.extraParams.searchname = userName;
myStore.load({addRecords: true});
```

But in my json store, the previously added records are still removed from the store. Why?

Comment: That should work. Suggest you post a fiddle: http://fiddle.sencha.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, I can't downvote my own post.

Evan's comment led to me putting some 50 lines of console.log() into the code.

Result: I was deleting all the records from the store before I did the partial refresh - not just those I wanted to reload.